# Can´t enable Zoom in my Webviewer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, zooming

I have this webviewer:

```
<WebView
     android:id="@+id/webView2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I´m using this code to force the webviewer to load the urls inside itself instead of loading them in the samsung internet explorer:

```
    inner class MyClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request:
    WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
        view?.loadUrl(request?.url?.toString())
        return true
    }
}
```

And these are the settings:

```
    webView2.apply {
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.setSupportZoom(true)
        settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        settings.useWideViewPort = true
        webViewClient = MyClient()

    }
```

However I can´t zoom in nor out the websites loaded inside my webviewer, any idea whats the problem?

Thank you in advance for your support

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please enable builtin zoom control:

```
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

If you want to disable zoom control on the screen, use this:

```
settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: it worked tyvm, btw , do you know a way to get the same result of loading urls inside webView instead of external browsers without having to change the API lvl to 21? I kinda want to have my app working in older versions of android too, and this is the only code that doesnt allow me to.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Try this link: "https://www.nbc26.com/robocalls/battling-robocalls-breaking-down-relentless-and-annoying-calls" . Does it work for you and letting you to zoom ? If so, please show your code for it